# Getting the following error while executing a python program

Tags: python-3.x

> [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>   [cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3.7', '-u', '']]
>   [dir: C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3]    [path:C:\cygwin64\bin;"C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\%PYTHON_HOME%";C:\Users\Jugal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]

Comment: As a general rule please consider providing the code you currently have and pointers about what have you tried so far

Comment: why do you have `"` signs in the path? why is the `PowerShell\v1.0\%PYTHON_` missing a `;`?

Answer (score 0):

Your Sublime Text 3 install expects the cmd to be a string not an array of strings.

The array `['/usr/local/bin/python3.7', '-u', '']` was interpreted as a single entry.

It is possible that you need some flags like `shell=False` to get rid of this behavior.